# Create Table Error - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I need help with this it keeps giving the same error in Oracle SQL Developer.

> Error starting at line : 15 in command -

```
CREATE TABLE B_BOOKING (
    booking_number int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    date_booked date,
    performance_order int,
    base_pay int,
    band_number int,
    concert_number int, FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES B_CONCERT(concert_number)
)
```

> Error at Command Line : 21 Column : 34 Error report - SQL Error:
>   ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis
>   00906. 00000 -  "missing left parenthesis"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be trying to declare a foreign key inline and have the syntax incorrect, you want:

```
CREATE TABLE B_BOOKING (
    booking_number int PRIMARY KEY,
    date_booked date,
    performance_order int,
    base_pay int,
    band_number int,
    concert_number int REFERENCES B_CONCERT(concert_number)
)
```

Also, you do not need a `NOT NULL` constraint on a `PRIMARY KEY` column.

Alternatively you can declare the constraint as:

```
CREATE TABLE B_BOOKING (
    booking_number int PRIMARY KEY,
    date_booked date,
    performance_order int,
    base_pay int,
    band_number int,
    concert_number int,
    CONSTRAINT constraint_name FOREIGN KEY ( concert_number )
                               REFERENCES B_CONCERT(concert_number)
)
```